# SP2010 and Report Builder

Tags: 2010, reporting-services, caml

I have an SSRS report integrated with SP 2010, the data in the report is loaded from a SP list. The current issue that I am facing is not being able to read minimum and maximum date time field for the given ID using CAML.

Can anyone tell me how can I do this ?

```
ID        RequestType             Status          Date

1         AAA                     Open            12/11/2012 10:10

1         BBB                     OnHold          12/11/2012 10:20

1         BBB                     Resume          12/11/2012 10:30

1         BBB                     OnHold          12/11/2012 10:40

1         BBB                     Resume          12/11/2012 10:50
```

I need to read the data in the following order, onHold and Resume.

Comment: can you add CAML code to make your question understandable :)

Answer (score 0):

If it is purely CAML you will need 2 queries and order by the date, ascending / descending and select a single result.

```
<OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="Date" Ascending="TRUE|FALSE" />
</OrderBy>
```

Thereby making your own MIN/MAX functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write custom code in VB integrated in to report file

[Check this post for using custom code in report builder](http://ittechnotebook.blogspot.com/2014/01/using-custom-code-in-report-builder-30.html)

Comment: This site is not for promoting your own blog posts. Please add more details to your answers now and in the future!